# How to specify when receiving payments, that customer should pay bank fees for international payments?

Tags: grammaticality, semantics

On my invoice I have statement like this, which is saying when client is doing international payment, client must pay bank fees for international payments:

> The cost of bank fees for international payments shall be borne by the
>   customer.

Is this semantically and grammatically correct for native and non-native English speakers?

Please note, that I am not native English language speaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grammatically and semantically, it's fine.

However (and yes, I realize this is slightly off-topic), speaking as an expert in international interbank payments (it's my job) I should tell you that if your bank forces you, as their customer, to bear the costs of international transfers (irrespective of whether you're sending or receiving the payment) then they are not providing a very good service. Virtually all international payments transfers run on systems that specify whether the cost of the transfer is borne by the sender OR the receiver OR shared between the two. You should be given the choice. International payments form an incredibly competitive market. I'd advise you to change your bank, or use a third-party provider :)